# Can only create folders on Samba since dist upgrade of client to Ubuntu LTS 22

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, samba

I want full owner access to the mounted system. As I used to have before the dist upgrade. I assume something about the fstab handling has changed.

Mount options are unchanged (fstab client):

```
//IP/nas     /path/      cifs    defaults,uid=myid,gid=myid,,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=user,password=pass,vers=1.0     0       0
```

I also checked my userid, it's still the same so the id in the config is correct. I updated only the system accesssing the drive.
As far I can see the problem is: The only write access I have is creating folders. Literally, I can't even do anything else with the folders I just created.

Example:

```
touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

mkdir succeeds.

Reqwuested additional info, output of "ls -ld . test.txt"

```
ls: cannot access 'test.txt': No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 1003 nogroup 0 Mär 26 19:57 .
```

Might be a timestamp of a test i did with root. I tried sudo touch and that worked. I deleted the file afterwards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer was, Ubuntu just didn't want to:
I checked "mount"
The result told me that Ubuntu for some reason added the paramters: noforceuid and noforcegid.

So I tried explicitly adding: forceuid and forcegid and now it works. Why do I have to argue with the system like that, anyone got an idea what the logic behind this was?

meaning the following fstab entry works:

```
//IP/nas     /path/      cifs    defaults,uid=myid,gid=myid,forcegid,forceuid,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=user,password=pass,vers=1.0     0       0
```